# I am Getting this error ProviderError: Must be authenticated!

Tags: dapps, hardhat, nodejs, hardhat-deploy, alchemy

```
ProviderError: Must be authenticated!
    at HttpProvider.request (/workspaces/Decentralized-Voting-Application-on-Ethereum-Blockchain/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/http.ts:88:21)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at EthersProviderWrapper.send (/workspaces/Decentralized-Voting-Application-on-Ethereum-Blockchain/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20)
    at getSigners (/workspaces/Decentralized-Voting-Application-on-Ethereum-Blockchain/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/helpers.ts:45:20)
    at getContractFactoryByAbiAndBytecode (/workspaces/Decentralized-Voting-Application-on-Ethereum-Blockchain/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/helpers.ts:288:21)
    at main (/workspaces/Decentralized-Voting-Application-on-Ethereum-Blockchain/scripts/deploy.js:2:18)
```

This is the error i am getting when i try to run  `npx hardhat run --network alchemy scripts/deploy.js`

My code of `hardhat.config.js`

```
/**
* @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
*/
require('dotenv').config();
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");
const { createAlchemyWeb3 } = require("@alch/alchemy-web3");

const { API_URL, PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;

module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.11",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {},
    alchemy: {
      url: API_URL,
      provider: () => {
        return createAlchemyWeb3(API_URL, PRIVATE_KEY);
      },
      gas: 2100000,
      gasPrice: 8000000000,
      saveDeployments: true,
    },
  },
};
```

How do I resolve it.